# how to update multiple tables columns using joins

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update like multiple tables with single query...like

```
update astatus a1,provider pr1,location br1 JOIN(
select br.id as bId,pr.id as pId,a.id as aId 
from astatus a,member m,provider pr,pricing_plan p,location br,pricing_scheme ps 
where date(a.next_payment_date)<=date(subdate(current_date, 1)) 
and   a.pricing_plan_id=p.id 
and p.pricing_scheme_id=ps.id 
and ps.type='SUBSCRIPTION' 
and a.status is null 
and m.astatus_id is not null 
and m.astatus_id=a.id 
and pr.member_id=m.id 
and br.provider_id=pr.id ) 
as dup 
ON a1.id=dup.aId,pr1.id=dup.pId,br.id=dup.bId
set a1.pricing_plan_id=null,pr1.auto_applied=0,br1.featured=0
```

but it's giving error..Please help me out

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `sql-server` **and** `mysql`. Do you need this statement to run on multiple DBMS?

Comment: And: "*it's giving error*" is not a valid error message in either DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
 ON a1.id=dup.aId,pr1.id=dup.pId,br.id=dup.bId
```

to

```
 ON a1.id=dup.aId and pr1.id=dup.pId and br.id=dup.bId
```